# Proguard to remove annotation from one package and keep them in other

Tags: java, proguard

I have package where I want to keep all annotations on classes, and I have package where all annotations should be removed from classes and fields. It seems I can either keep all annotations in all packages (with -keepattributes *Annotation*) or remove all of them, but I want to choose where to keep and where to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

ProGuard indeed keeps the specified attributes in all classes. I can see how finer control could be nice in some cases, but it would require some more complex syntax.

At this time, you can perhaps process the packages independently.

Comment: After some research I think processing packages independently is the only way to solve this problem.